Solving a combined limit with an $1^{\infty}$ form nested inside a 0×∞ form
I came across this limit problem:
$\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty}\left\{\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^x-e^2\right\} \cdot x^2$
Plugging this into desmos, one can see that the limit approaches $\frac{2 e^2}{3}$
The way I tried to solve this is first simplify this limit:
$(\frac{x+1}{x-1})^x$$\hspace{1cm}$ ...(1)
Clearly this is of the $1^{\infty}$ form, and by using the general formula for this indeterminate form, one gets:
$\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^x=e^{\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2 x}{x-1}}$$\hspace{1cm}$ ...(2)
I then proceeded like this:
$\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty}\left(e^{\frac{2 x}{x-1}}-e^2\right) x^2=\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} e^2\left(e^{\frac{2}{x -1}}-1\right) x^2$
Plugging this into desmos, however, I realized that the limits do not match. One can easily solve the above expression using the general formula
$\lim _{x \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{e^x-1}{x}\right)$= 1
The resulting limit tends to +$\infty$
I am not able to understand why on simplification the value of the overall limit changes when the value of the inner limit does not i.e., when (1)=(2).
What went wrong? Is there a right way to solve this question using a method similar to mine?

First, recall the relation $e^x = \lim_{n\to+\infty} (1+x/n)^n$, which in the present context it is good to write as $e^y = \lim_{x\to+\infty} (1+y/x)^x$.
Your Eq. (1) could thus be written:
$\left( \frac{x+1}{x-1} \right)^x = \left( \frac{1+1/x}{1-1/x} \right)^x = \frac{(1+1/x)^x}{(1-1/x)^x} \to \frac{e^1}{e^{-1}} = e^2$ as $x \to \infty$.
Your limit $\lim_{x\to\infty} \left( \left( \frac{x+1}{x-1} \right)^x - e^2 \right) x^2$ will require a sharper estimate since the factor $x^2$ diverges and the rest tends to 0. This leads to your Eq. (2), which I'd correct to:
$\left( \frac{x+1}{x-1} \right)^x = e^{x (\ln(1+1/x) - \ln(1-1/x))} = e^{x (2/x + 2/(3x^3) + \ldots)} = e^{2} e^{2/(3x^2) + \ldots} = e^2 \left( 1 + \frac{2}{3 x^2} + \ldots \right)$
In the second step the Taylor expansion $\ln(1+1/x) = \sum_{k=1}^ {\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k \, x^k}$ was used. Returning to the full expression:
$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left( \left( \frac{x+1}{x-1} \right)^x - e^2 \right) x^2 = \lim_{x\to\infty} \left( e^2 \left( 1 + \frac{2}{3 x^2} + \ldots \right) - e^2 \right) x^2 = \lim_{x\to\infty} e^2 \left(\frac{2}{3 x^2} + \ldots \right) x^2 = \frac{2e^2}{3} + 0$.

What does it mean to say that $x^2$ diverges, and how does that necessitate a sharper estimate? (I just graduated high school, so I'm not familiar with divergence/convergence other than the basic idea of divergent sums (like 1-1+1-1....). Apart from that, I got the solution. Thank you.

Diverging is just means the magnitude grows without bound, but it doesn't necessarily mean that the expression tends to either $+\infty$ or $-\infty$. For example: (a) $x^2$ diverges (grows without bound) and tends to $+\infty$ as $x$ tends to $+\infty$. (b) $x^2 \sin(x)$ diverges but does not tend to $+\infty$ as $x \to +\infty$. (c) $\sin(x)$ neither diverges nor converges as $x \to +\infty$. In my answer above, it was somewhat unnecessary to use the less specific "diverges"; I could have said $x^2$ tends to $+\infty$.
